# Android, Iphone USB connection

Tags: android, ios, usb, battery

Is it possible to send battery power via USB by android or iOS devices? I did some research about USB connection with Android and found USBhost to send and receive data but what about power?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS it is only possible with the 30 pins connector to my knowledge.

But you will have to join the Apple MiFi program: https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/
This is needed to be allowed to create hardware that use the dock connector of an iOS device.